# Error while building Jboss developer studio 9.1.0 Beta 2 from source

Tags: tycho, jboss-developer-studio

I have downloaded jboss-devstudio-9.1.0.Beta2-src.zip and am building it from source.

However, the build is failing with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) on project com.jboss.devstudio.core: Execution default-package-plugin of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin failed: One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) on project com.jboss.devstudio.core: Execution default-package-plugin of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin failed: One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-package-plugin of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin failed: One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called.
```

So it is looking for a git repository in the directory, but I have downloaded source code zip.

Any ideas how I can resolve this error and proceed with the build?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-3598

Note that as of devstudio 10.x, sources are public so you can just fetch the latest from github and build from that.

https://github.com/jbdevstudio/jbdevstudio-product

Or for a specific release, you can download a zip of sources:

https://github.com/jbdevstudio/jbdevstudio-product/releases/tag/jbdevstudio-10.1.0.GA